# bootstrap fixed nav in single page site links issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I have single page site [alampk.com](http://alampk.com/)
Here I have fixed navbar at top, but when I click any link like `exp`,`portfolio`...
it does move to that section but top `50px` portion comes behind navbar, I tried many things (css and jquery) but nothing fixed this issue.

I tried the following jquery

```
$(".nav a").click(function(){
   $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-50);
});
//but this executes before reaching to target section of page 
//and also I not sure -50 will be accurate value for required positioning
```

I also created a `div` before navbar as

```
<div id="navPlaceHolder"></div>
//css
#navPlaceHolder{
    height:50px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

but this only work for top most section

Comment: Please add some screenshots, and post the navbar code.

Comment: I have mentioned url, it is static html page, debug the code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve here is impossible without Javascript.

You've changed the `scrollTop` but you need to do it after some milliseconds to get it working, e.g:

```
$(".nav a").click(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 50);
  }, 10);
});
```

If you don't want to wait those milliseconds, you can also prevent the default behavior and simulate it:

```
$(".nav a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = e.target.href, id = "#" + href.substring(href.indexOf("#") + 1);
  $(window).scrollTop($(id).offset().top - 50);
});
```

Now, if you prefer a completely no-javascript solution, you'll need to workaround by putting a `padding-top` of 50px in each of your `section` tags, so the title will be visible in the way you want to.

Comment: great @Buzinas! you made my day

Answer (score 0):

I really, in fact, think it's easy to do with just CSS. (Thanks Thomas for the tip! ;-)).

If you include a hash, #, the browser window will scroll itself into that position, trying to achieve the minimum possible position to make the element wholly visible. This, in a case of a fixed navbar, it's not desired.

The idea is to create an empty element before each linked element you want to direct to, just using CSS:

```
     element-you-want-to-target::before {
       display: block;
       content: " ";
       margin-top: -150px; /* the height of your navbar that will put the empty element up*/
       height: 150px; /* the height of the empty element that goes behind your navbar
       visibility: hidden; /* just in case */
       pointer-events: none;
     }
```

You have to be careful if before using this method, tried with putting some margins to the body or the element you wanted to target, because, in a responsive environment, won't work properly, showing the blank space.

Here is a pen to show what I did. I hope would be useful --> https://codepen.io/Mau-Di-Bert/pen/mjQwXw

Bye!