# Fixed nav-bar hides content in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have fixed navbar that hides content when using tabs. The navbar display properly when I'm not navigating between tabs, when I click one the tabs the navabr hides content including headers of the tabs.

[image]

After clicking one of the tabs, the content gets hidden.
[image]

I tried using this, but only works when not navigating between tabs.

```
body{
margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Guys here's my example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhdk9s28/)
and I think the cause of this might be my javascript, when I'm not using `hash` it's working fine. I need the `hash` when the user refresh the page, the last open tab needs to be active.

```
 $('#sign-up-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});

// store the currently selected tab in the hash value
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
});

// on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('#sign-up-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

**Solved:**
I have solved it by changing my code to the following.

```
$('#sign-up-tabs').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // add this line
   window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).tab('show');
 });
// on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
  var hash = window.location.hash;
 $('#sign-up-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

[on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhdk9s28/)

Comment: If you could provide a snippet that replicates the issue, it would be easier to get help.

Comment: The margin should probably be applied to the container wrapping the tabs control. Can you provide some code or create a plunker?

Comment: I am afraid you will have to provide us with more code to be able to help you troubleshoot this issue.  There is not enough information posted to know what is going on

Comment: give us the url so we can look at it or create a fiddle with the same issue. You have a css problem but we can't guess what it is based on your post.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your navbars container to use `display: block`.

If it is not yet inside a container, you should put it inside a div, and it will probably work like a charm.

For example, if you're using:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- the rest of your code -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

You should change it to something like:

```
<div style="height: 80px">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- the rest of your code -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I have same problem, not worked form me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572762/bootstrap-fixed-nav-in-single-page-site-links-issue

Comment: can u please check my question and help me out

Comment: @alamnaryab add extra `margin-top:80px` to the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Give the top padding to the container according to the navbar height.
Example if your navbar height is 90px then you have to give top padding 90px to the container.

```
.container {
    padding-top:170px;
}
```